# (Why) does jQuery .click() require a callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following jQuery code:

```
function next() {
    //some code here
}

function previous() {
    //some code here
}

$("#next").click(function(){
    next();
});

$("#previous").click(function(){
    previous();
});
```

This works, but this doesn't:

```
$("#next").click(next());

$("#previous").click(previous());
```

Why is this happening? Is there a problem in my code, or is this just a thing with jQuery? Note: `#next` and `#previous` refer to two buttons in my html file.

Comment: By putting brackets after the function name you are executing the function and assigning the return value of the function as the callback rather than the function itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works (if the functions `next` and `previous` are defined):

```js
$("#next").click(next);

$("#previous").click(previous);
```

In this case the `next` and `previous` are also callback functions, the difference between the two is,

when you call this line

> `$("#next").click(next());` the function is executed immediately, and you are passing **the result of the next function** to the eventHandler of jQuery.

and in this case

> `$("#next").click(next);` you are passing the function **next** to the EventHandler of jQuery.

**Btw.:** in the jQuery API Documentation (https://api.jquery.com/click/) it shows all parameters for the **click** function and the required types it states: *"...**handler** Type: Function( Event eventObject ) A function to execute each time the event is triggered. ..."*

Comment: Why the downvote? did I write something that is incorrect? How could i improve my answer?

Answer (score 4):

The callback should be a `reference` to the function.

*Why `$("#next").click(next());` doesn't work?*

`func()` is a function call and not a reference, which is why it is called immediately.

---

This,

```
$("#next").click(function(){
    next();
});
```

is a preferable way in case you need to pass arguments.

Else,

```
$("#next").click(next) //notice just the signature without ()
```

Comment: Why is there a downvote on all answers? If there is a scope of improvement everyone is free to clarify or edit the asnwer.

Answer (score 1):

try like this you will get your answer,

```
function next() {
    //some code here
}

function previous() {
    //some code here
}

$("#next").click(next);

$("#previous").click(previous);
```

working demo [jsfiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Praveent696/0cvrbaxk/1/)

Answer (score 0):

What is going on there is a little bit obscured by the syntax of anonymous functions `function() { ... }`. What you are doing by that is passing a function, without calling it. And I want to explain how this works:

If you have a simple function

```
function next() { return 5 };
```

It will simply return the value 5, if you call it from somewhere:

```
a = next(); // value of a will be 5
```

But what you can do too, is to pass the whole function to `a`. This is possible, because functions in JavaScript are actually objects:

```
a = next;
b = a();    // value of b will be 5
```

If you look at the syntax, it shows you, that putting parentheses `()` at the end of a function invokes it, and returns the return value. While the naked string, without parentheses hands you the function itself.

So what is a callback now, and what does `click()` like to get as a parameter? A callback function is a function, that gets called later; we actually hand it over, to get called later. `click()` would like to get such a function as parameter, and it should be clear now, that we have to pass the function without parentheses, to enable `click()` to call it later, instead of just passing a `5` to it.

```
$("#next").click(next);
```

So how does then the initial syntax with the anonymous function work?

```
function() { next(); }
```

actually wraps your `next()` into another function, which is anonymous – because it does not have a name – but is working in the same way as a named function. You can even set a variable by it:

```
a = function() { next(); }  // a will be the anonymous function that calls next()
```

But calling that function `a()` will return nothing, because the anonymous function does not return a value (To be exactly: every function call in JavaScript is returning at least `undefined`, but that's a technical detail).
It can even be called immediately by putting parenthesis at the end of it:

```
a = function() { return next(); }()   // value of a will be 5
```

Adding the `return` there will make sure, the return value of  `next()` will be passed through the anonymous function.

This should make clear why

```
$("#next").click(function(){ next(); });
```

is working, and why

```
$("#next").click(next());
```

is not, but

```
$("#next").click(next);
```

will be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

$("#next").click(next); would work. Notice parenthesis are not required as the function/callback handler should be passed as a parameter.